# HTTP response headers: multiple Link values

Tags: html, seo, http-headers

I'm working on SEO for a Rails App.

The website is fully localized, and I'm following [this google article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) to add **hreflang alternate** links to the pages.

The HTML links in the `<head>` are ok.

I'm having some troubles with the [response headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5).

I understand that I'm supposed to provide values for each alternative version of the page, but I'm not sure about how to set multiple values.

I tried to pass them as a *comma separated list*. Browsers seem to receive it correctly, but since individual values contain semi-colons it looks *wrong*.

Is there any reference on it?
Even an example webpage that is known to implement it correctly would help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have no experience with this, but according to the [examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5.5) in the same RFC they get separated by comma:

```
Link: </TheBook/chapter2>;
      rel="previous"; title*=UTF-8'de'letztes%20Kapitel,
      </TheBook/chapter4>;
      rel="next"; title*=UTF-8'de'n%c3%a4chstes%20Kapitel
```

It’s indirectly confirmed by [5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5.3) (emphasis mine):

> Note that extension relation types are REQUIRED to be absolute URIs in Link headers, and MUST be quoted if they contain a semicolon (";") or comma (",") (**as these characters are used as delimiters in the header itself**).

Comment: Just for the record there's a later version of that RFC, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8288